# Why does an affine translation before and after a rotation shift the image incorrectly?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, affine-geometry, transformational-geometry

Given an image I of four pixels:

```
I = [[0, 0], [1, 0],
     [0, 1], [1, 1]]
```

Translate so that origin is at the centre of the image (subtract -1 from x and y):

```
I = [[-1, -1], [0, -1],
     [-1, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Rotate the image by 90 degrees:

```
I = [[-1, 1], [-1, 0],
     [0, 1], [0, 0]]
```

Translate back (by adding back 1):

```
I = [[0, 2], [0, 1],
     [1, 2], [1, 1]]
```

Note that all Y points are shifted up by 1. The image should instead be:

```
I = [[0, 1], [0, 0],
     [1, 1], [1, 0]]
```

Is there a reason this is happening? I am unable to rotate images about their centre without incuring this shift in the y direction. Is it something wrong with the translations? I've spent considerable time on this, and I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.

Edit it appears the amount I was translating by was incorrect, it should be 0.5:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: isn't the center $(0.5, 0.5)$? In general, you need to translate by $(\frac{-w}{2}, \frac{-h}{2})$

Comment: Thank you Siddarth! I had made the mistake of forgetting that I am working with an index starting at 0.